# Show 2 decimal only if the decimal is not .00

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

So, I have a requirements to show decimal only if the value of the decimal itself is not .00

I'm using this currently `.ToString("#,###,##0.##")` but I have issue below

Expectation

```
1000 -> 1,000
5522.13 -> 5,522.13
55.1 -> 55.10
```

Reality

```
1000 -> 1,000
5522.13 -> 5,522.13
55.1 -> 55.1
```

The part 55.1 will only show one decimal instead of 55.10. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that with a single format specifier. You're going to have to use some conditional logic and format differently in the two cases. There would be various ways to do that but here's one that's fairly simple:

```vb
Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(1000.0))
        Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(5522.13))
        Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(55.1))

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Function FormatNumber(number As Double) As String
        Dim temp = number.ToString()

        Return If(temp.Contains(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator),
                  number.ToString("n2"),
                  number.ToString("n0"))
    End Function

End Module
```

Note that I believe that that should work for all values that do not need to be represented using scientific notation, which should be fine for most people. If you have a very large value then `ToString` may output scientific notation that contains a decimal separator, even though the actual number has no fractional part.

Another option, which tests the number rather than the string representation of the number, is as below:

```vb
Private Function FormatNumber(number As Double) As String
    Return If(Math.Round(number) = number,
              number.ToString("n0"),
              number.ToString("n2"))
End Function
```

Note that the format specifiers are reversed in that second case, because the test is for the absence of a decimal point where the first example tests for the presence of a decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a simple `.Replace(".00", "")` might work for you.

```
var numbers = new [] { 1000.0, 5522.13, 55.1 };

foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    var formatted = number.ToString("#,###,##0.00").Replace($"{CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}00", "");
    Console.WriteLine(formatted);
}
```

Or:

```
Dim numbers = {1000.0, 5522.13, 55.1}

For Each number In numbers
    Dim formatted = number.ToString("#,###,##0.00").Replace($"{CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}00", "")
    Console.WriteLine(formatted)
Next
```

Those both give me:

```
1,000
5,522.13
55.10
```

Comment: For the record, "#,0.00" will do the same as "#,###,##0.00", as will "n2".

Comment: One potential issue with that code is that it doesn't take culture into account. In some cultures, the dot is the group separator rather then decimal separator. In such cultures, the number 1000.0 would be formatted as "1.000,00" by your code and then the replacement would make that "10,00". That's why I specifically used `CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` in one of my examples. If this code won't be used cross-culturally then you're OK. If it might be then you should use `.Replace(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + "00", string.Empty)`.

Answer (score 0):

use `ToString("#,#.#0")`

```
var numbers = new [] { 1000.0, 5522.13, 55.1 ,15003.2};

foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    var formatted = number.ToString("#,#.#0");
    Console.WriteLine(formatted);
}
```

result:

```
1,000.00
5,522.13
55.10
15,003.20
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x431YW)